# 'parcel' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ERROR for Parcel bundler in Vanilla TYPESCRIPT Code

Tags: node.js, npm-start, parceljs, typescript

This error is showed up when I ran the code for an Arkanoid Game published on freecodecamp articles. I am not able to set up the configuration correctly for the game. I expected it to run the game but it didn't do the same. While debugging it kept throwing errors regarding its build. I have no idea as I have learned it online but this error is not getting resolve.
I am attaching both the debugger image and the error image along with the log file text, where it showed the error.
[DEBUG CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFJDp.png)

[TERMINAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7MWu.png)

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'start'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.5.3
2 info using node@v15.9.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 4ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 5ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 5ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 6ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:file:D:\arkanoid-ts-startHere\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\WELCOME\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 2ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 3ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 27ms
19 verbose npm-session 84c35795bdcebad3
20 timing npm:load Completed in 60ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 146ms
22 timing command:start Completed in 163ms
23 verbose stack Error: command failed
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
23 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
23 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
24 verbose pkgid ts-parcel@1.0.0
25 verbose cwd D:\arkanoid-ts-startHere
26 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
27 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
28 verbose node v15.9.0
29 verbose npm  v7.5.3
30 error code 1
31 error path D:\arkanoid-ts-startHere
32 error command failed
33 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c parcel serve src/index.html
34 verbose exit 1
```

This is package.json file

```
{
"name": "ts-parcel",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel serve src/index.html",
    "watch": "parcel watch src/index.html"
},
"type": "module",
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "parcel": "^1.12.4",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
}
}
```

This is index.ts file

```
import {CanvasView} from './view/CanvasView';
import {Ball} from './sprites/Ball';
import {Brick} from './sprites/Brick';
import {Paddle} from './sprites/Paddle';
import {Collision} from './Collision';

//Images
import PADDLE_IMAGE from './images/paddle.png';
import BALL_IMAGE from './images/ball.png';
import BRICK_IMAGE from './images/brick.png';

//level and colors
import{
    PADDLE_SPEED,
    PADDLE_WIDTH,
    PADDLE_HEIGHT,
    PADDLE_STARTX,
    BALL_SPEED,
    BALL_SIZE,
    BALL_STARTX,
    BALL_STARTY
} from './setup';

//helpers
import {createBricks} from './helpers';

let gameOver = false;
let score = 0;

function setGameOver(view: CanvasView){
    view.drawInfo('Game Over!');
    gameOver = false;
}

function setGameWin(view: CanvasView){
    view.drawInfo('Game Won!!!');
    gameOver = false;
}

function gameLoop(
    view: CanvasView,
    bricks:Brick[],
    paddle: Paddle,
    ball: Ball,
    collision: Collision
){
    console.log("draw!");
    view.clear();
    view.drawBricks(bricks);
    view.drawSprite(paddle);
    view.drawSprite(ball);
    //move ball
    ball.moveBall();

    //move paddle and check as it won't exit the playField
    if(
        (paddle.isMovingLeft && paddle.pos.x > 0) || 
        (paddle.isMovingRight && paddle.pos.x < view.canvas.width - paddle.width)
    ){
        paddle.movePaddle();
    }

    collision.checkBallCollision(ball, paddle, view);
    const collidingBrick = collision.isCollidingBricks(ball, bricks);

    if(collidingBrick){
        score += 1;
        view.drawScore(score);
    }

    //GAME OVER!!! when ball leaves playField
    if(ball.pos.y > view.canvas.height) gameOver = true;
    //if game won, set gameOver and display win
    if(bricks.length === 0) return setGameWin(view);
    //return if gameOver and don't run the requestAnimationFrame
    if(gameOver) return setGameOver(view);

    requestAnimationFrame(() => gameLoop(view,bricks,paddle,ball,collision));
}

function startGame(view:CanvasView){
    //reset display
    score = 0;
    view.drawInfo('');
    view.drawScore(0);

    //create collision
    const collision = new Collision();

    //create all bricks
    const bricks = createBricks();

    //create all paddle
    const paddle = new Paddle(
        PADDLE_SPEED,
        PADDLE_WIDTH,
        PADDLE_HEIGHT,
        {
            x: PADDLE_STARTX,
            y: view.canvas.height - PADDLE_HEIGHT - 5
        },
        PADDLE_IMAGE
    )

    //create a ball
    const ball = new Ball(
        BALL_SPEED,
        BALL_SIZE,
        {x: BALL_STARTX, y: BALL_STARTY},
        BALL_IMAGE
    );

    gameLoop(view, bricks, paddle, ball, collision);
}

//create a view
const view = new CanvasView('#playField');
view.initStartButton(startGame);
```

This is CanvasView.ts file

```
import {Brick} from '../sprites/Brick';
import {Ball} from '../sprites/Ball';
import {Paddle} from '../sprites/Paddle';
import { BRICK_IMAGES } from '~/setup';

export class CanvasView{
canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
private context: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;
private scoreDisplay: HTMLObjectElement | null;
private start: HTMLObjectElement | null;
private info: HTMLObjectElement| null;

constructor(canvasName: string){
    this.canvas = document.querySelector(canvasName) as HTMLCanvasElement;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
    this.start = document.querySelector('#start');
    this.info = document.querySelector('#info');
}

clear(): void{
    this.context?.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
}

initStartButton(startFunction: (view:CanvasView) => void): void{
    this.start?.addEventListener('click', () => startFunction(this));
}

drawScore(score: number): void{
    if(this.scoreDisplay) this.scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score.toString();
}

drawInfo(text: string): void{
    if(this.info) this.info.innerHTML = text;
}

drawSprite(brick: Brick | Paddle | Ball): void{
    if(!brick) return;

    this.context?.drawImage(
        brick.image,
        brick.pos.x,
        brick.pos.y,
        brick.width,
        brick.height
    );
}

drawBricks(bricks: Brick[]): void{
    bricks.forEach(brick => this.drawSprite(brick));
}
}
```

The above codes are the mainframe of the game. Hope it helps to resolve.

Comment: Have you added `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to load an ES module, we need to set “type”: “module” in this file or, as an alternative, we can use the .mjs file extension as against the usual .js file extension.

In your `package.json` file add this:

```
{
  "type": "module",

}
```

For an example:

```
{
  "name": "esm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

If this doesn't work uninstalling both global and local versions of parcel:

```
npm uninstall parcel
npm uninstall -g parcel
```

Then install it using this command:

```
npm install parcel --save-dev
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with this but it is showing the same error.

Comment: @ShivamSharma I updated the answer. Can you try and tell me how it goes? BTW it'll be much easier if you can share the code, where you are getting the error.

Comment: Thank You so much!!! :) It has resolved the error. Now the program is running and the game started to load, only there is some build error with the image file. I hope it gets resolved too.

Answer (score 1):

I have been getting this error while using `parcel index.html` to start the parcel deployment server.

On reading the official [documentation](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/) I found out the correct command to do that:

```
npx parcel index.html
```

It worked as expected on using that command!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.Parcel is a bundler if you look in your package.json file you will see you most likely have parcal index.html .To fix this problem i ran the command

npx parcel index.html

this will install the necessary files to get your developement running .